# What does callJSNonFinalObjectCallbackObject refer to?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, crash, eas

I have an app built which is running fine on Expo Go & development builds but crashes in preview builds. Every time it crashes, the same message is brought up in the crash logs in Xcode:

```
Thread 7 name:  com.facebook.react.JavaScript
Thread 7 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1bb374bbc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1dbedc854 pthread_kill + 208
2   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x18b1ab6ac abort + 124
3   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x18b1ff6d8 __assert_rtn + 268
4   projectname                            0x10465f588 0x1045a8000 + 750984
5   projectname                            0x104667790 0x1045a8000 + 784272
6   projectname                            0x10478ca94 0x1045a8000 + 1985172
7   projectname                            0x10478c7dc 0x1045a8000 + 1984476
8   JavaScriptCore                         0x18b6913a0 JSC::callJSNonFinalObjectCallbackObject(JSC::JSGlobalObject*, JSC::CallFrame*) + 412
9   JavaScriptCore                         0x18be6e5e4 JSC::handleHostCall(JSC::JSGlobalObject*, JSC::CallFrame*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallLinkInfo*) + 828
10  JavaScriptCore                         0x18be96d08 llint_link_call + 484
11  JavaScriptCore                         0x18b6240a8 llint_entry + 164320
12  JavaScriptCore                         0x18b620ed8 llint_entry + 151568
13  JavaScriptCore                         0x18b620ed8 llint_entry + 151568
14  JavaScriptCore                         0x18b620ed8 llint_entry + 151568
15  JavaScriptCore                         0x18b620ed8 llint_entry + 151568
```

Assuming something is wrong with my JavaScript code, but can't find any information about this message online.

Additional information:

- Developed in React Native through Visual Studio Code
- Using latest version of eas-cli
- Project uses quite stack navigation and quite a few libraries including Firebase, YouTubeVideoPlayer, AsyncStorage, Expo Clipboard, WebBrowser etc.